# Switch ROMs, still seamlessly use Apps and its data

Tags: backup, restore

I am presently using a rooted LG P500 running stock 2.3.3. I am very fond of trying various ROMs and recently got hooked to [unofficial CM10 Android 4.1.1 (JellyBean)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1811325).

Working with such unofficials or even official nightly builds has a problem of receiving frequent update. When ever such update comes I have to wrap up all my app and its data using [Titanium Backup](http://matrixrewriter.com/android/) (TB) and for safety backup my present ROM completely using [CWM recovery](http://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager).

After installing the new ROM, I will download TB alone and restore all my apps.  Though the TB has batch mode for "Restoring all missing apps and its data", TB asks for confirmation before installing every app and prompt for "Done/Open" after installing every app.  This kills the purpose of running a batch.

Now my questions:

1. Is there any way I can switch between ROMs but keep the apps (with its data) installed in a common location for all ROMs
2. Automate the restore option (in new ROM) such that with one click and a wait of few minutes should get my phone back with all apps and data intact?

My dream use case with either question will be like: While I am in 2.3.3 ROM I would simply backup the present apps and its data to SD card and install the new ROM. When the new ROM is installed, I would like to have the apps that where backed up in my 2.3.3 ROM to come back with its data by doing something that is not daunting, but ready to wait for a while.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pro version of [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackupPro) supports batch restore without user interaction. It's worth it.

Comment: Please provide a link if possible

Comment: Thanks, I was so near but didn't notice the pro version's benefits for so long!