# How can I bulk install apps with Play Store or App-Brain?

Tags: google-play-store, installation, app-brain

I'm trying to restore a new device with apps from my old device, but neither Android Market nor AppBrain seems to automatically bulk install them? When I use the Execute method in AppBrain it seems to only send me to manual install of all apps, which probably would take a long time since I use a number of apps.

Is there some way to make AppBrain bulk install a list in a batch or is it possible to move the apps from my old device to the new one?

Comment: Does it need to be done with Play Store or App Brain? Or are other ways also ok?

Comment: It must be done using either because my other device is dead

Comment: Actually it used to work with app brain but seems google crippled bulk installs through market.

Comment: AppBrain bulk install still works fine.  I just tested it on my Galaxy Nexus running 4.1 Jelly Bean.  I posted the instructions as a separate answer.

Comment: That's odd, when I did a factory reset on my phone, the Play Store automatically downloaded and installed all the apps I had installed before.

Comment: SaintWacko maybe backup of profile on same device does that? Nice btw.

Comment: @grm - That could be it. I thought I remembered there being a setting for it, because I went in and turned it off, as I didn't want all the apps back on it. I can't find that setting now, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you've previously installed AppBrain and synced your device, you can do the following:

1. From Google Play Market download and install [AppBrain](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.apps) and [Fast Web Installer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.apppusher) apps.
2. Open the Fast Web Installer and sign in with your Google account (same one you are using on Play Store).
3. Open the AppBrain app, and sign in with your AppBrain account.
4. Go to Preferences, and then use the "Enable Fast Web Install" option.
5. Under Menu go to "More lists..." option, select the previously synced list, tap the "Add all apps" button, and tap the back button.
6. Tap the "Execute" button, and after reviewing the permissions tap the "Install" button.  This should download and install apps in batch, without having to confirm each one separately.

You can also create lists of apps via AppBrain's site, and these lists should show up in the app.

Comment: The "Fast Web Installer" application is no longer available on the Android market. :(

Answer (score 15):

This might be a new feature of newer versions of Android (I'm using 4.4), but I can easily mass install apps from the `Play Store`.

How to mass-install apps with the Play Store:

1. Open the Play Store
2. Go to My Apps
3. Go to All
4. Keep your finger pressed on an app that has not been installed yet for a second or so.
5. Now the play store goes into selection mode, you can simply select all the apps you want and press the "Install" button at the top when you
   re done.

Comment: +1 Only works from the play store app (no mass selection option in the web store) so this must be done on the device.

Answer (score 11):

I don't know of a way to do this. I recently bought a new phone, and to save myself the tedium of manually installing 40 odd apps, I went to the Google Play Store using a desktop browser.  It will already have a list of apps you have installed under My Apps, so you can quickly spin through the list and install them - you don't need to wait for each app to install.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Play Store app itself can send and receive applications to a local device (over the internet, not Bluetooth).

On each device:

1. Open Google Play Store
2. Tap your profile icon
3. Tap Manage apps & device
4. Under "Share apps" select Send or receive
5. Approve the location permission dialog
6. Select apps and confirm the pairing code.

On both the sending and receiving side there's a button to select-all.

Comment: OMG this is the answer I needed! TIL. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

You can install Titanium Backup in your old device and backup all "user installed" apps + data to SD card.  In your device, put this SD card and install Titanium Backup again and restore "user installed" apps + data.

Though I have not tried this across devices, I had tried this with same device using different ROM. I had backed up from a stable ROM and whenever I install a new ROM I would use the above method to install all my apps with its data.

I had already asked [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27695/switch-roms-still-seamlessly-use-apps-and-its-data) question and it has been answered referring Titanium Backup.

Comment: Device is dead so it's not possible.

Comment: Titanium Backup requires root.

Comment: It won't help now, but for future protection have your Titanium backups synced to DropBox or Google Drive to recover from dead devices.