# How can I bulk install apps from market links without confirmations?

Tags: backup, restore

I'm searching an app (or whatever) in order to be able to re-install the apps I've currently installed, after performing a clean flash.

I found apps that can list the apps installed in a file with market links, but if I want to bulk install these apps, it's asked my manual operation for each.

How can I bypass this operation?

(For anyone wondering, I'm searching for something different from TitaniumBackup).

Thank you guys!
Cheers

edit: [This solution](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/28097/259623) seemed to fit my needs but the app "Fast Web Installer" is no longer available unluckly

Comment: If you have access to the APK files you can simply create a batch file containing an install command for each apk: `adb install app1.apk` (ADB on device has to enabled of course, and adb must be available on your PC).

Comment: But with this procedure the apps are not going to install through the PlayStore right? I would like to install them from the PlayStore using the market links.